# Usereducer state is alway undefined when used with useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

I am trying to use useReduce along with `useContext`,  when I console the value in a reducer, I am getting array of an object in the console, but when I try to access the state from another component, I am getting the state is undefined. State.map() is completely empty.

Here is my  code

App.js

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from 'react';

import Uploadproject from './Uploadproject';
import Getprojects, { projectget } from './Getprojects';
import reducer from './reducer/Usereducer';

export const Contextstate = createContext();

const App = () => {
  const initialvalue = null;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialvalue);

  const updatestate = async () => {
    const data = await projectget();
    dispatch({ type: 'add', payload: 'from app.js' });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updatestate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Contextstate.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
        <Uploadproject />
        <Getprojects />
      </Contextstate.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Usereducer.js

```js
import { projectget } from '../Getprojects';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'add') {
    projectget().then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      // state = [ ...result]
      state = result;
      console.log(state);
      return state;
    });
  }
};
export default reducer;
```

Getprojects.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { Contextstate } from './App';

const Getprojects = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Contextstate);
  const getstate = () => {
    dispatch({ type: 'add', payload: 'from getprojects' });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getstate();
  }, []);

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        {state &&
          state.map((cur) => {
            return (
              <div key={cur._id}>
                <h1>{cur.title}</h1>
                <p>{cur.description}</p>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    deletproject(cur._id);
                  }}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Getprojects;
```

When I try to access the state from Getprojects component, its value is undefined. But inside a reducer if I, console am getting an array of object. In any other component, the state is undefined.
Any idea???

Comment: Reducer functions are synchronous, they can't use asynchronous code. What is `projectget`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle asyn logic in your application by using redux, you should pick one of `Async Redux Middleware` packages

- redux-thunk (more easiest to config and good for small projects)
- redux-saga
- redux-observable etc.

Or you can just use `useEffect` and dispatch only result actions to it. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProjectActionStart());
    projectget()
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        // state = [ ...result]
        state = result;
        console.log(state);

        dispatch(getProjectActionStart(state));
        return state;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        dispatch(getProjectActionFailed());
      });
  }, []);
```